# webpack and amd modules integration

Tags: requirejs, webpack, amd

I have the following scenario in a web application:

I have some external js files containing multiple amd modules (they've been generated by typescript, but I don't want to use ts-loader, for now).
each one of these files contain more than one amd module, such as:

```
define("Namespace/Module1", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    ....
}
define("Namespace/Module2", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    ....
}
```

Inside my main application I request modules exported by these files using

```
var a = require("Namespace/Module1").
```

I used SystemJs until now, and using correct configuration, everything's working, but I would like to start using webpack for bundling and I don't know how to add these files as "require" dependencies.

I tried to add them as script tags after importing requireJS, but (of course), webpack loader uses its own "require" loader and it doesn't work.

Using externals in webpack configuration makes webpack consider that they are not modules, but globals, so it excludes **require("aaa")** from the generated bundle and expects a global **aaa** variable

```
function(module, exports) {

     module.exports = aaa;

}
```

How can I tell webpack that when he's generating my bundle he should still use **require("Namespace/Module")** but before, calling all "**define**"s in my external files?

I hope my explanation is enough and If I am doing something wrong, if am following bad practices, or something, please explain.

Thanks in advance